# Scala error when try to write Output File

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, databricks

I found this error when try to write a new output file from the code:

**java.io.FileNotFoundException: s3a:/tfsdl-ghd-wb/raidnd/Incte_19&20.csv**

```
val inputFile = "s3a:/tfsdl-ghd-wb/raidnd/rawdata.csv" //  INPUT path 
val outputFile = "s3a:/tfsdl-ghd-wb/raidnd/Incte_19&20.csv" //  OUTPUT path 
val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd")
val fileSystem = getFileSystem(inputFile)
val inputData = readCSVFile(fileSystem, inputFile, skipHeader = true).toSeq

val writer = new PrintWriter(new File(outputFile))
writer.write("Sales,cust,Number,Date,Credit,SKU\n")
filtinp.foreach(x => {
val (com1, avg1) = com1Average(filtermp, x)
val (com2, avg2) = com2Average(filtermp, x)
writer.write(s"${x.Date},${x.cust},${x.Number},${x.Credit}\n")
})
writer.close()

def getFileSystem(path: String): FileSystem = {
val hconf = new Configuration() // initialize new hadoop configuration
new Path(path).getFileSystem(hconf) // get new filesystem to handle data
```

Comment: I tried with different paths(local as well) and access permissions are verified too.

Comment: not sure if can be related to the fact I'm using HDFS and that require temporal write operations to a path I'm not able to access.. how can I check?

Comment: why is this question related to Spark ?

Comment: I think you're missing a '/' after the s3a prefix.

Comment: I was thinking can be related to lack of Spark configuration in databricks cluster since not able to write to hdfs, being reading this Problem is in order to write data using file system based source you'll need a temporal directory, this is a part of the commit mechanism used by Spark, i.e data is first written to a temporary directory, and once the tasks are finished, automatically moved the processed file to the final path

Comment: weird in code put val outputFile = "s3a://tfsdl-ghd-wb/raidnd/Incte_19&20.csv" (just doubled checked now in my notebook)and error always prompt only '/' after the s3a prefix. what does even possible?

Comment: error always complain with one "/"

Comment: does not work either with "dbfs:/mnt/tfsdl-ghd-wb/raidnd/Incte_19&20.csv" or "dbfs:/mnt/tfsdl-ghd-wb/raidnd/" checked path exists and have access to

Comment: From what I'm reading "The PrintWriter is a local resource, bound to a single machine and cannot be serialized."... so I can not use it in databricks cluster, any alternative?

Comment: Use dataframe writers!! `df.write.csv(path)`

Comment: how is this done in this code lines? 
with df.coalesce(1).write.csv("/your/location/data.csv") instead "writer.write" ?
also how do I include the columns ?